# How to Prevent Leaflet Sidebar from moving the map on the x-axis when it appears?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, sidebar

I am discovering Leaflet maps, and I decided to use a sidebar that appears when a marker is clicked, from this : https://github.com/Turbo87/leaflet-sidebar . As you can see on the video in the link, when you click the marker, the sidebar appears but also drags the map on the x axis, and I did not manage to find where I can prevent that. I would like to make it appear without moving the map.

Here is also the link of the example with the code : http://turbo87.github.io/leaflet-sidebar/examples/

I tried to add this, so it stays at the current coords when I click :

```
marker.on('click', function () {
     var coord = e.latlng;
     var lat = coord.lat;
     var lng = coord.lng;
     map.panTo([lat,lng]);
}
```

but it doesn't work, it only does if I set the coords before like this:

```
marker.on('click', function () {
     map.panTo([47.392882, 0.683022]);
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried to change some values in the css to see the way it changes, to understand where this moving happens but I didn't get any answer in doing that. I tried making a
```javascript
marker.on("click", function() {
 var coord = e.latlng;
 var lat = coord.lat;
var lng = coord.lng;
map.panTo([lat,lng]);
}
```
but again, it still moves

Comment: You should really add the code to to your question by [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58064292/edit) it. And read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) how to ask. This question will not be answered as it is.

Answer (score 0):

it can be done by changing the code in the L.Control.Sidebar file

```
show: function () {
   if (!this.isVisible()) {
         L.DomUtil.addClass(this._container, 'visible');
       if (this.options.autoPan) {
            this._map.panBy([-this.getOffset() / 2, 0], {
                duration: 0.5
            });
       }
         this.fire('show');
     }
 },

 hide: function (e) {
     if (this.isVisible()) {
         L.DomUtil.removeClass(this._container, 'visible');
        if (this.options.autoPan) {
            this._map.panBy([this.getOffset() / 2, 0], {
                duration: 0.5
            });
        }
         this.fire('hide');
     }
     if(e) {
         L.DomEvent.stopPropagation(e);
     }
 }
```

deleting this part

```
if (this.options.autoPan) {
     this._map.panBy([this.getOffset() / 2, 0], {
       duration: 0.5
     });
}
```

Comment: in case there's no need to delete the code but to control the value of the `autoPan` options parameter when creating an instance of Sidebar: `L.control.sidebar('sidebar', { autoPan: false })`